# Magento Onepage Checkout ChildHTML pages not updating?

Tags: magento

I am working on a theme for Magento and simply modifying the base theme. When I am editing the app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml file and any of the other files within the onepage folder it doesn't update the actual process of the checkout. Even if I erase the whole file the contents of that step on the checkout are still there. Is this content being pulled from another spot? ( i have cache disabled )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- turn on template hints
- add print_r(get_included_files()); at the end to your php to see what files and from where are included
- make sure that your site is not APC cached

Comment: I did check all of that and it didn't give me any hints at all. This is just mind boggling, I'm editing the billing.phtml file and nothing is changing I even checked all of the other themes and there is no other billing.pthml file it can be including. Color me confused.

Comment: The file for ONLY billing seems to be included from a different location for some reason.

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.pthml

Comment: grep the name billing.phtml in layout directory to see in which layout file i t is defined

Comment: Still in the persistent directory as of 2016 for 1.9.2

Answer (score 1):

Has the exact same problem, for some reason there is another billing.phtml in the persistent directory that is being used....

Comment: THIS! I was about to give destroy everything around me.